# Replace with maximum value for specific columns by group/ID in R

Tags: r, data.table, max, dplyr, apply

I'm trying to convert a dataset that has multiple observations per person over a period of time. For example, person 1 can be obese and not obese (just overweight) during this time. Here's an example from person 1:

```
ID     Obese     Overweight
1       NA          NA
1       NA          NA
1       0           1
1       1           0
1       0           0
2       NA          0
2       0           1
2       0           NA
```

I need to replace the values in each column to "1" if a 1 appears at all WITHIN THAT COLUMN, across a specified number of columns (there are 700+; e.g. c(5:749)) BY "ID". Ideally, the output would look like:

```
ID     Obese     Overweight
1       1           1
1       1           1
1       1           1
1       1           1
1       1           1
2       0           1
2       0           1
2       0           1
```

First I changed all the NAs to 0's; I then figured I could take the maximum along each column and replace (by ID), but can't find documentation on how to do this by group ("ID") AND a given set of columns (i.e. c(5:749)). Also I would not want to create new columns, but rather just replace values within columns already existing within the data frame.

I got it to work for a single variable, but couldn't translate this into a loop to go through a set of variables...

```
dat2 <- dat[, Obese:= max(Obese), by=ID]
```

Also I think a loop would take too long given the data size. Any other recommendations? Thanks in advance. Here's an example dataset:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,18))
dat$id <- as.character(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3))
dat$ob1 <- as.character(c(NA,NA,0,1,0,NA,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
dat$ob2 <- as.character(c(NA,NA,1,0,0,NA,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0))
dat <- dat[,-1]
```

As far as the linked paged using "lapply", it doesn't seem to work in the case where all values are NA (or 0) for a given individual. In this scenario, it seems to "fill in" / impute with values from other columns (which never appeared in the column in the original dataset); this was clearly spotted when a binary variable was imputed/replaced with a continuous value. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: In the linked question, you can see more options in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for linking this page; it appears to be what I'm looking for, but I still encounter an error. For example, in columns where all values are NA for a given individual, it seems to "fill in" / impute with values starting from other columns (which never appeared in the column in the original dataset); this was clearly spotted when a binary variable was imputed/replaced with a continuous value. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Okay, maybe you can post an example that shows that? I don't really understand the case being described.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. It looks like there was an issue in my data table -- after re-running everything, the code on the linked page worked (and was a LOT faster than running in a loop). I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think `tapply` is helpful for this case.
You can find the max for each id by

```
with(dat, tapply(ob1, id, max))
```

My solution is:

```
dat$ob1 <- as.numeric(dat$ob1)
dat$ob2 <- as.numeric(dat$ob2)
dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0

dat$ob1 <-  with(dat,tapply(ob1,id,max)[id])
dat$ob2 <-  with(dat,tapply(ob2,id,max)[id])

dat
   id ob1 ob2
1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1
3   1   1   1
4   1   1   1
5   1   1   1
6   1   1   1
7   2   1   1
8   2   1   1
9   2   1   1
10  2   1   1
11  2   1   1
12  2   1   1
13  3   0   1
14  3   0   1
15  3   0   1
16  3   0   1
17  3   0   1
18  3   0   1
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do this without having to specify for each variable? For example, I have hundreds of columns, and cannot feasibly write out a tapply command for each one. How would I write this code to carry out the command over, say, columns 5:749?